# How to load-balance Spring UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter when on different server

Tags: java, spring, jwt, load-balancing

I am currently developing a REST-application which needs to be very scalable. From what I have learned about load balancing, one should split up the actual application into independent parts. So far I've separated creating accounts and the login from the actual application. I followed [this](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) tutorial to implement JWT. Is that best practice or can this solution be improved?

However, I have my actual REST-application as a separate project. Obviously, these two applications need to work together. How can I accomplish that? Is there a way to store the Token & access it in the second application?

Someone told me to follow microservice architecture [according to this tutorial](https://medium.com/@arjunac009/spring-boot-microservice-with-centralized-authentication-zuul-eureka-jwt-5719e05fde29).

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

With the JWT pattern as described in that auth0 blog, the services are designed to be *stateless*.  In fact, the example code explicitly disables the Spring session. All information required for authorization are fully contained in the JWT token itself and cryptographically protected.

Therefore, there is no need to store or share the token between multiple services / applications, as long as they are all configured with the same `SECRET`.  Each load balanced service simply needs to verify the token received by the client, using the `JWTAuthorizationFilter` class.

From a best practice perspective, instead of "manually" issuing JWT tokens from each service, consider using an oauth2 or OpenID Connect service.  This can be your own service, or you can use a 3rd party service such as auth0 or okta.  (OpenID Connect is an extension to oauth2).

You can read more about oauth2 from https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-apis-and-spas-with-oauth2/

Comment: if a client logs in on the first server, will the second server accept the token when I am using ```JWTAuthorizationFilter```?

Comment: Also, OAuth2 is used for granting access to third-party apps and I don't think this is what I need

Comment: Yes, the second server will accept the token as long as both servers use the same secrets.  Also, OAuth2 is not only for granting access to third-party apps.  Many if not most use it to grant API access to their own apps only.